# Get transloadit result file names before actual encoding

Tags: transloadit

It’d be easier for me to pass the resulting video encoding paths complete with file names to hidden inputs in a php form than actually waiting for the encoding to be completed or deal with assembly responses to be fed to an import/decode/update DB script.
Didn’t find any reference to this in the Transloadit documentation. Is it even possible to obtain the file names before the process ends and setting the `waitForEncoding` option in Uppy to false?

Comment: you may have a look at this FAQ page https://transloadit.com/docs/faq/get-result-link-immediately/ I think you will find it helpful

Comment: Thanks @ifedapoolarewaju. That was posted following this question here and some interaction on Transloadit forums.